# How to make own text editor for math equation?

Tags: math, text, editor, formula, equation

**I'm using C# on Windows (but I can also use C++)**

What I want to make is just an own **text editor that I can write/edit mathematical equations/formulas.**

Reason why I'm looking for this function is that the calculations of my structural analyzing programs are only editable with in my C# code. **I want my programs provide a function that a user can add their own formulas for design checking or whatever so that my programs can be more widely used.**

I know how to parsing equation of string form to multiple variables in code so I can compute what I want. However, I really have no idea that **how to display own text editor.** I think it can't be done by textbox and only thing I can think of is using opengl api. But I believe there should be easier and efficient way to this job done.

My programs are currently run on windows only but I'm planning to make OSX version and web version as well. I don't mind if solution only available for windows only or not. If anyone knows easy way to display own text-box, please help me. I will really appreciate for it. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: what language? environment? ...  in textbox is doable if you have font containing all the symbols you need however you also need richedit properties (separate formatting for each symbol) so you best bet would be use UNICODE ... however you also need to use and ship UNICODE font so its working on all machines... or render the editor as Canvas image directly on your own using sprites ...

Comment: oops. I'm using C# on Windows but I can use C++ too.

I'm not just hoping to enter mathematical or Greek signs, but also I want to add such sin cos square, root, limit, integral such complex equations that used in engineering mathematics.

Comment: you need to create a text format to store your expressions and then create a function that renders it ... or converts into format readable by your text-box (rtf or whatever). I hope that by text-box you mean Memo (more lines of text with variable formatting)... edit boxes  (single line) usually do not support variablke formatting ... at least in environments I am used to. btw there are also libs to do the same out there